# Yii Framework, how to fetch related table data?

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I am new to yii and the model relation is new to me. I am currently doing a system that has a table structure:

```
products
PK id
brand

product_locales
PK id
FK product_id
name
locale

product_relations
PK id
FK product_id
FK related_id
```

my Product model relation:

```
public function relations()
        {
                return array(
            'productlocales' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductLocale', 'product_id'),
            'relations' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Product', 'product_relations(product_id, related_id)')
        );
        }
```

then my Product Locale Relation:

```
public function relations()
        {
                return array(
            'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'product_id')
        );
        }
```

in my Product Controller when I call this code:

```
$product = ProductLocale::model()->findByPk(1);
var_dump($product->product->relations);
```

it outputs the id and brand of a related product from the product table. but what I want to output is all the locales of the product, which is the name and the locale.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the product_relations table, and seems like the relation whith Product is HAS_MANY, not MANY_MANNY.

In any case, if I have understood, you need find the id of product and then find all the product_locale with this id:

```
$prodLoc=ProductLocale::model()->findByPk(1);
$arrayProdLoc=ProductLocale::model()->findAllByAttributes('product_id'=>$prodLoc->product_id);
```

ArrayProd will have models for all product_locale related with the same product.
If you want show this information in a gridview, you probabli will want a DataProvider:

```
$prodLoc=ProductLocale::model()->findByPk(1);
$provider=CActiveDataprovider('ProductLocale',array (
          'criteria'=>array(
                      'condition'=>'product_id='.$prodLoc->product_id,
          ));
```

You can also define a new self-relation into product_locale Model:

```
public function relations()
    {
            return array(
        'product' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Product', 'product_id'),
        'productsLocRelated'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'ProductLocale',array('product_id'=>'product_id')),
    );
    }
```

So you can have all products_locale by:

```
$prodLoc=ProductLocale::model()->findByPk(1);
$arrayProdLoc=$prodLoc->productsLocRelated;
```

Note: I haven't tested the code.